# Looking for a no-cost music streaming app for Android which includes an "offline mode"

Tags: gratis, android, offline, music, streaming

I'm looking for:

1. A music streaming app
2. Which doesn't cost money to use
3. Which includes an "offline mode"
4. And which works on Android
5. Preferably which offers access to a large number of songs (millions of songs) for free

This way, I can keep on listening to cached/synchronized music even when I'm disconnected from the Internet.

I'm willing to look at advertising or to listen to ads, as long as I don't have to pay any monthly fee to use the app.

---

Slacker Radio Plus offers an offline mode.  But it costs $4/month, and so therefore is not what I'm looking for.

Spotify Premium, Google Play Music, and Deezer Premium Plus each also offer an offline mode.  But each costs $10/month, and so they're not what I'm looking for either.

Comment: Hmmm. I did more research and discovered one (mediocre) option. My local public library offers patrons access to a digital media service called Hoopla.  The Hoopla app lets patrons "borrow" music albums for seven days each.  (Behind the scenes, the app downloads the album to the patron's Android device, then deletes it seven days later.)  The more each patron borrows, the more it costs the library, so in my city, each patron can only borrow eight albums in any one-month period.  In practice, the seven-day limitation sounds annoying enough that I don't think I'll ever bother trying the service.

Comment: Anytime! And good luck :) I don't know of such a service (as I'm not using streaming apps; I rarely listen to music on my phone), but while waiting for answers you might wish to peak into my lists of [Online & Network Players](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_network) plus [Jukeboxes and more](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_jukeboxen). Just afraid the specific "music streaming" category is missing, so those apps might be spread amongst these two lists …

Comment: @Izzy:  :)  Hmmm.  Having looked at your lists, it looks like [Vibe Vault](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.code.android.vibevault) might be good.  I like obscure types of music, but it I did a bit of keyword searching through like the archive.org [live music archive](https://archive.org/details/etree) and it seems there's some music there that I might like.  Though the archive.org music collection seems to be far smaller than that of, say, Spotify.

Comment: I've never bought any audio files from any online music store, and don't want to buy any now.  I do own a small CD collection.  I suppose that another way for me to listen to music while offline would be for me to rip part or all of it to my phone's removable MicroSD card.  This would cost me nothing, and it wouldn't actually be that difficult.  Windows Media Player can rip to (CBR) MP3.  All I'd need to do would be to look through the basement and to find an external CD-ROM drive to plug into this laptop.

Comment: There are also solutions for your own "sound-cloud": you could rip your collection and place it on your hard-disk, then have it served over the network. Examples are in those lists as well, plus in [DLNA / uPnP Server and Clients](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_dlna). // Once you've found something suitable, remember: you can always [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) :)

Comment: In the end, I bit the bullet and started paying $10/month for Spotify Premium.